# Magento 2 Init script after page load

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, controllers, swatches

Is there any option to init (text/x-magento-init) script after page load? Example, I am working on a simple quickview feature and my controller returns my a layout - phtml file - with rendered html and script with config like this below:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
        "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
            "jsonConfig": ...
        }
    }
}
```

New content is appended to modal wrapper and new popup is initialized. Is there any option to fire (maybe some kind of event od body/document) which triggers again init process for Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer script?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of how to do this. I need to initialise swatches on ajax loaded product list as not working with infinite scrolls so may be similar?

Answer (score 0):

MAy be you try **afterRender** function to initialize function after load something you want, Take a look on following document : 
[Js Referrence](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html)

Comment: thank for your reply! Nice try, but I am working with mixin which based on $.widget (mage.catalogAddToCart), so KO template functions are not visible there

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `.trigger('contentUpdated')`
When you get the Ajax Content trigger the contentUpdated event so the new `data-mage-init` to be evaluated. e.g.

```
var contentBlock = this.element.find('.page-footer');
    $.ajax({
        url: this.options.contentsUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'form_key': FORM_KEY,
            node: node.id
        },
        context: contentBlock,
        showLoader: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        contentBlock.html(data).trigger('contentUpdated');
    });
```

credits to this [answare](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248677/magento-2-how-to-call-text-x-magento-init-on-ajax-success).