# Magento 2 : How to call text/x-magento-init on Ajax success

Tags: uicomponent, jquery, knockoutjs, magento-2.2.5, requirejs

I am in need to trigger some script with "text/x-magento-init" on ajax call but I am unable to do so.

```
trigger('contentUpdated')
```

contentUpdated is also not working in my case.

I am using contentUpdated as:

```
$('.page-footer').html(response.categoryProducts);                        
$('.page-footer').trigger('contentUpdated');
```

On console log(response.categoryProducts) I can see that x-magento-init script but the effect is not shown on frontend on using this way.

Any help ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for my question at last. I used 'applyBindings()' as 'contentUpdated' was not working in my case. Like

```
$('.page-footer').replaceWith(data.categoryProducts);
$('.page-footer').trigger('contentUpdated');
if ($.fn.applyBindings != undefined) {
      $('.page-footer').applyBindings();
}
```

Hope that this may help some one else as well. For more details have a look at this link: https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-uicomponent-reinit-ajax-reload/

Comment: Thanks @Narendra for posting answer, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
    var contentBlock = this.element.find('.page-footer');
    $.ajax({
        url: this.options.contentsUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'form_key': FORM_KEY,
            node: node.id
        },
        context: contentBlock,
        showLoader: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        contentBlock.html(data).trigger('contentUpdated');
    });
```

OR

```
$('.page-footer').append(row).trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Comment: Tried but no luck :( not getting where I am wrong

Comment: Did you get any response into response.categoryProducts?

Comment: Yes I am getting whole Html in its response, and all html content is displaying correctly accept that x-magento-init block. And that script with x-magento-init is also I am getting in response, I have checked by console log whole data

Comment: try this $('.page-footer').append(response.categoryProducts).trigger('contentUpdated'); In which file you ahve write this code?

Comment: Actually we have used Amasty extension for shop by ajax, so I am writing this amasty extension js file i.e. amShopbyAjax.js

Comment: Ohke maybe your js file is not loading in all pages hence your content maybe not update you can try with header file or footer file

Comment: Not getting, as ajax is been called in this file itself.